# LibreOffice calc to PGAdmin 3?

Tags: sql, linux, libreoffice, pgadmin

I have one table with 9 columns and 1010 rows. 
Now, I want to turn this table into SQL database so I can manipulate data from PGAdmin 3?

I literally only need an option to export LibreOffice Calc file into SQL file or PGAdmin 3 readable file?
What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Hi Dax Can you give me a sample Eg a couple of rows. I might be able to help you. Also could you provide the types of data. Eg string, integer, float etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In libre office calc **save as** and select the type as

> **csv**

Then create the table and column types in Postgresql (psql) / Pgadmin

Then import (right click on table select import)

Just one word of **warning** if you **create primary key** and have columns or rows **empty** this will fail.

Works fine. Tried and tested.

Here's a simple example

```
12  Alison  Norton  road    district    nr20    10  12.4
13  Bob     Down    road    district    nr6     11  0.4
14  karen   milf    road    district    nr20    200 9
```

`CREATE TABLE test1
(
  "Import-id" integer PRIMARY KEY,
  fname character(10),
  lname character(10),
  add1 character(10),
  add2 character(10),
  zip1 character(10),
  aint integer,
  amoney money
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE test1
  OWNER TO postgres;`

You can either use this command

```
copy your_created_table FROM '/your/path/to/file.csv' USING DELIMITERS ',' CSV;
```

Or you can right click on the table and use the import function as shown below

[image: Pgadmin import menu]

Don't forget to change the type **from text** to **csv**

[image: Pgadmin import wizard]

All the best hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, i don't have CSV as option when trying to save from LibeOfficeCalc as you can see here:

[link](http://imgur.com/pei8fNM)

Comment: Scoll down a little more Dax (The type scoll bar -> | ) Text .cvs is onefrom the bottom (use the arrow button if you like :) ).. I'll delete this comment afterwards. Only human :)

Comment: Hi @DaX Here's a link for you https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Importing_and_Exporting_CSV_Files

Comment: I've never seen someone being helpful as you are. Thanks a lot man! I really appreciate it!